# MySQL update if exists else insert throws syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement

Trying to update existing records based not on ID but specific usernames with no luck. I wrote the following query but I got a syntax error I can't find.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE username = 'REMOTEUSER1')
    THEN
        BEGIN
            UPDATE users
                SET username = 'REMOTEUSER1', password = 'BJxp98YkVbt4', exp_date = '1650991560', member_id = 1, is_mag = '0', play_token = '', reseller_notes = ''
                WHERE username = 'REMOTEUSER1'
        END;
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO users (
                username,
                password,
                exp_date,
                member_id,
                is_new,
                play_token,
                reseller_notes
            ) VALUES (
                'REMOTEUSER1',
                'BJxp98YkVbt4',
                '1650991560',
                1,
                0,
                '',
                ''
            )
        END;
    END IF;
```

Comment: What's the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `IF-ELSE` conditional statement construct is supported to be used through `FUNCTIONS` or `STORED PROCEDURES` that can't use it like a normal query.

If your `username` column is `UNIQUE index` or `PRIMARY KEY` I would use [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` Statemen](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

```
INSERT INTO users (
    username,
    password,
    exp_date,
    member_id,
    is_new,
    play_token,
    reseller_notes
) VALUES (
    'REMOTEUSER1',
    'BJxp98YkVbt4',
    '1650991560',
    1,
    0,
    '',
    ''
) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
 password = 'BJxp98YkVbt4',
 exp_date = '1650991560', 
 member_id = 1, 
 is_mag = '0', 
 play_token = '', 
 reseller_notes = '';
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=8dd53b655ce9b56d0c6422c0f8995e6b)

Comment: It worked! Thanks! But I need to understand why the above didn't work. Could you explain..?

Comment: @CDoc I add more detail about that.

Answer (score 0):

If `is_mag` is a bit(1) (boolean), then it's likely the update portion where you set it to '0'

either set the boolean to an *integer* value of 0, or prefix it with b

i.e.
`my_bool = b'0'`